# How does reveal.js resize elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

I am trying to understand how [`reveal.js`](https://revealjs.com/) resizes elements dynamically.

To see this, adjust the height of the page and see how elements (to a certain degree) shrink as the page shrinks.

However, using chrome inspector, I cannot see how this shrinking is actually happening, either in CSS or Javascript.

(My interest comes from wanting to improve it, if possible, but I was surprised how hard it was to figure out how it works at all.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Presentations are configured with a "normal" resolution, meaning the resolution the presentation was originally authored at. This is currently set to 960x700 by default.

Based on that resolution and the aspect ratio derived from it the framework will apply CSS 2D transforms to fit your content inside of any screen size. There are configuration values to control all of this including limits on how much the framework will ever scale your content.

```
Reveal.initialize({

    ...

    // The "normal" size of the presentation, aspect ratio will be preserved
    // when the presentation is scaled to fit different resolutions. Can be
    // specified using percentage units.
    width: 960,
    height: 700,

    // Factor of the display size that should remain empty around the content
    margin: 0.1,

    // Bounds for smallest/largest possible scale to apply to content
    minScale: 0.2,
    maxScale: 1.0

});
```

Comment: This was not the case when I submitted the question. I privately implemented something very much like this, I should see if this is better than my own code.

Comment: With this code, width is indeed changing. but the height stays the same, no matter what is the value in it. It seems that low amount are simply lowering the box (in cube animation). is this a bug?

Comment: @hakim very nice! is it possible to adjust only how images scale? (e.g. have embedded images display at a consistent width based on the device size?)

Comment: Im using angularjs to display the default template of reveal.js but everything looks very small, when I check the properties attributes of the slides and the size in pixels are correct width:950 on the configurations but the size is too small when it renders to even read the content. please let me know if you know how to fix it, I'm going to put a plunker tomorrow if you wanna see it. thanks

Answer (score 10):

Have you heard of media queries? This is a technique deployed through CSS that allows you to affect the styling of elements based on the width and height of the window. Here is how it's used for reveal.js https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/reveal.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px), (max-height: 600px) {
    .reveal .slides {
        font-size: 0.82em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px), (max-height: 400px) {
    .reveal .slides {
        font-size: 0.66em;
    }
}
```

Read On: [MDN CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Mini Tut: [CSS Media Queries & Using Available Space | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: In fact, you were right, and wrong! :)

The resizing does not occur in 'resize', it occurs because of the CSS:

`@media screen and (max-width: 900px), (max-height: 600px) {
 .reveal .slides {
  font-size: 0.82em;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px), (max-height: 400px) {
 .reveal .slides {
  font-size: 0.66em;
 }
}`

Comment: Yeah just found it and Edited my answer before seeing your comment. :)

Comment: Please see @hakim's answer. He's the creator of reveal.js.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code hosted on github https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/js/reveal.js you can see exactly what it's doing.

It checks for browser CSS features like 2d and 3d transforms

```
    // Detect support for CSS 3D transforms
supports3DTransforms = 'WebkitPerspective' in document.body.style ||
'MozPerspective' in document.body.style ||
'msPerspective' in document.body.style ||
'OPerspective' in document.body.style ||
'perspective' in document.body.style
```

It uses basic event listeners

```
    // Force a layout when the whole page, incl fonts, has loaded
window.addEventListener( 'load', layout, false );
...
/**
* Binds all event listeners.
*/
function addEventListeners() {

window.addEventListener( 'hashchange', onWindowHashChange, false );
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
...
```

The source code actually has decent commenting so you should be able to learn quite a bit.

Comment: I have read the source code, and explored it in chrome inspector. However, I can't find any bit which would adjust font sizes. The function which runs on resize (layout) moves slides up and down, but doesn't do any resizing that I can see?

Comment: If I delete the entire contents of the 'layout' and 'resize' functions, and set supports2DTransforms and supports3DTransforms to false, then the resizing still occurs. While I agree the code is well laid out, these aren't the places (suprisingly) where the resizing is occurring!

Comment: @Chris Jefferson - in the CSS https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/reveal.css I suspect its the media queries that change the font-size based on screen size "@media screen and (max-width: 700px),(max-height: 400px)"

Answer (score 1):

Reveal.js also uses the `zoom` property to control the resizing of complete slide on small widths. It dynamically changes the value of `zoom` property which you can notice if you keep resizing the window.

Comment: Im using angularjs to display the default template of reveal.js but everything looks very small, when I check the properties attributes of the slides and the size in pixels are correct width:950 on the configurations but the size is too small when it renders to even read the content. please let me know if you know how to fix it, I'm going to put a plunker tomorrow if you wanna see it. thanks